# rxjava Observable composition

Tags: rx-java

I create some entity, which have method `isCorrect: Observable<Booledn>` in loop. I need intersection of last boolean of each correct. I make it by creating array of Observable, is there more clean way?

```
API.getData().
.doOnNext(data -> 
 {
  List<Observable<Boolean>> correctAll = new ArrayList<>();
  Observable.from(data).forEach(r -> {
  Entity entity = new Entity();
  entity.set(r);
  correctAll.add(entity.correct());
  });
  Observable.combineLatest(correctAll, args -> {
    for (Boolean o : (Boolean[]) args)
         if (!o) return false;
                       return true;
    })
.subscribe(button::setEnabled);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
API.getData()
   .flatMap(
        data-> Observable.from(data)
               .flatMap(d -> { Entity entity = new Entity();
                               entity.set(r);
                               return entity.correct().last();}))
   .all(b -> b)
   .subscribe(button::setEnabled);
```